# logback DailyRolling seems does not work for me

Tags: logback

I am using a logback dailyroller, the application is up and running always, but it seems it does not create log file every day as I expected. below is my setting,
My question is if my application is running but if there is no output to the log file, will the daily log file still be created every day?

```
<property name="LOGS" value="./log" />

<appender name="RollingFile"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOGS}/out.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
        <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz
        </fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        <!--timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>40MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicyi-->
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not able to find log file, change your property tag from `<property name="LOGS" value="./log" />` to `<property name="LOGS" value="/log" />` and also add the root tag.

**logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <property name="LOGS" value="/log" />

  <appender name="RollingFile"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOGS}/out.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
      <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz
      </fileNamePattern>
      <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
  </appender>

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

Also, If there is no logging event then they'll be no rollover. So if your log back configuration policy is set to daily rollover and your application does not produce a single logging event for the entire day then there'll be no log file created for that day.